# Getting more rows back than what I should while splitting tables into seperate tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I have a temp customer table

```
create table #tmpCustomer
(
    ID int identity(1,1),
    CustomerID nvarchar(128),
    CustomerName nvarchar(50),
    FirstName nvarchar(50),
    LastName nvarchar(50),
    DateCreated nvarchar(50),
    CreatedBy int,
    YearBuilt nvarchar(50),
    IsActive bit,
    CustTypeID nvarchar(128),
    CustomerTypeID int,
    CompanyID int,

    Line1 nvarchar(50) not null,
    Line2 nvarchar(50) null,
    Line3 nvarchar(50) null,
    City nvarchar(50) not null,
    ZipCode nvarchar(15),
    StateID int not null,
    NewCounty nvarchar(20),
    SubDivisionID int null
)
```

That I am populating from an originating customer table and am using this to populate the temp table

```
declare @separator char(1);
set @separator = ',';

insert into #tmpCustomer
(CustomerID, CustomerName, FirstName, LastName, DateCreated, CreatedBy, YearBuilt, IsActive, CustomerTypeID, CompanyID, Line1, Line2, Line3, City, ZipCode, StateID, CountyID, NewCounty, SubDivisionID)
select 
    c.CustomerID, 
    c.CustomerName,  
    LastName = Case
     When CHARINDEX(@separator, c.CustomerName, 1) - 1 <= 0 Then c.CustomerName
     Else SUBSTRING(c.CustomerName,1,CHARINDEX(@separator, c.CustomerName, 1) - 1)
      End,
    FirstName = Case
     When CHARINDEX(@separator, c.CustomerName, 1) - 1 <= 0 Then NULL
     Else SUBSTRING(c.CustomerName,CHARINDEX(@separator, c.CustomerName, 1) + 1, Len(c.CustomerName) - (CHARINDEX(@separator, c.CustomerName, 1) ))
      End,
    GETDATE(), 
    1, 
    case when c.YearBuilt is NULL then 'N/A' else c.YearBuilt end,
    c.EnabledInd, 
     case when CustomerTypeID = '4F0B6446-441D-46B8-81CB-B0E8A94624A7' then 1 else 2 end, 
    1,
    c.Address1,
    c.Address2,
    null,
    c.City,
    c.ZipCode,
    11,
    null,
    Case when c.County <>  '' then  County ELSE 'N/A' end as "County",
    null
from [Customer] c
where c.CompanyID = '21DE6731-5E6C-11D5-AF81-00D0B74725F6'
```

This has a total count of 33165 records, which is exactly what it should be.

Next is that I am having a seperate table to hold the addresses

```
create table #tmpAddress
(
    ID int identity(1,1),
    Line1 nvarchar(50) not null,
    Line2 nvarchar(50) null,
    Line3 nvarchar(50) null,
    City nvarchar(50) not null,
    ZipCode nvarchar(15),
    StateID int not null,
    CountyID int null,
    SubDivisionID int null
)
```

and if I run this

```
insert into #tmpAddress
(Line1, Line2, Line3, City, ZipCode, StateID, CountyID,SubDivisionID)
select cr.Line1, cr.Line2,cr.Line3, cr.City, cr.ZipCode, 11, 0, null from #tmpCustomer cr
```

Then I get the correct amoutn of addresses at 33165

The problem that I am running into is the County.

I have a table of counties, called County and the issue seems to be when I join the County table to get its ID's. Here what is returning more records than it should and it returns 34546 records, which is over a 1000 more than the other one.

```
insert into #tmpAddress
(Line1, Line2, Line3, City, ZipCode, StateID, ct.CountyID,SubDivisionID)
select cr.Line1, cr.Line2,'', cr.City, cr.ZipCode, 11, ct.CountyID, null from #tmpCustomer cr
inner join Exo.dbo.County ct on ct.County = cr.NewCounty
```

I don't know what is going wrong and maybe someone could point it out to me so I can get the 33165 records for the tmpAddress table

Comment: try with Distinct and check how many records are coming

Comment: @mohan111, I am getting back 32840

Comment: @Chris check that `county` is indeed unique in the `Exo.dbo.County` table. You may have duplicates in there causing your record count to increase.

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to by [unfinishedmonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4282926/unfinishedmonkey), it looks like you have duplicate values in `Exo.dbo.County.County`, you can check with a query like:

```
SELECT c.County, COUNT(*)
FROM Exo.dbo.County c
GROUP BY c.County
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY c.County
```

If this returns any records, then you have duplicate records in `Exo.dbo.County` with the same value in the `County` field, which in turn is leading to you getting multiple rows in your resultset for a single row from `#tmpCustomer`.

You could solve this in a couple of ways, firstly by removing records from `Exo.dbo.County` so that all `County` values in that table are unique, or by amending your `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cr.Line1, cr.Line2,'', cr.City, cr.ZipCode, 11, ct.CountyID, NULL 
FROM #tmpCustomer cr
INNER JOIN Exo.dbo.County ct ON ct.County = cr.NewCounty
```

If this query still returns more records than you get from `SELECT Line1, Line2, cr.City, cr.ZipCode FROM #tmpCustomer`, I'm not sure what the problem could be. If it returns less records, then you must have some records in #tmpCustomer which have a `NewCounty` value which doesn't appear at all in `Exo.dbo.County.County`, so you might want to consider a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` if that's the case.